Font size is uneven in different components of next js 14 app
I need some help with an issue. The font sizes are uneven in different components of my portfolio website, which I developed using Next.js 14 App Router. I'm using CSS modules.
I have a single CSS module called default.module.css that contains all the font styles and breakpoints.
Please take a look and guide me on how to fix this issue. Feel free to ask if you need any further details.
default.module.css:
.defaultBg {
  background-color: var(--dark);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100dvh;
}

.containerSpace {
  width: 80.5%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .containerSpace {
    width: calc(100% - 2.75rem);
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 601px) and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .containerSpace {
    width: calc(100% - 12rem);
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1001px) and (max-width: 1400px) {
  .containerSpace {
    width: 79.5%;
  }
}

.headingSpace {
  margin: auto auto 1.45vw auto;
}

.textSpaceSmall {
  margin: auto auto 0.75vw auto;
}

.textSpace {
  margin: auto auto 1.25vw auto;
}

.textSpaceLarge {
  margin: auto auto 1.25vw auto;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .headingSpace {
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
  }

  .textSpaceSmall {
    margin-bottom: 0.75rem;
  }

  .textSpace {
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
  }

  .textSpaceLarge {
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
  }
}

.headingStandard {
  font-size: 1.25vw;
  font-weight: 600;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .headingStandard {
    font-size: 16px;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 401px) and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .headingStandard {
    font-size: 17px;
  }
}

.headingMedium {
  font-size: 1vw;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: var(--white);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .headingMedium {
    font-size: 16px;
  }
}

.textLarge {
  line-height: 1.75vw;
  color: var(--white);
  font-weight: 500;
}

.textExtraLarge,
.text2XL {
  font-weight: 500;
  color: var(--white);
  line-height: 2vw;
}

.textNormal {
  line-height: 1.85vw;
}

.textExtraLarge {
  font-size: 1.2vw;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .textNormal {
    line-height: 24px;
  }

  .textLarge,
  .textExtraLarge,
  .text2XL {
    line-height: 26px;
  }

  .textExtraLarge {
    font-size: 15px;
  }
}

.text2XL {
  font-size: 1.3vw;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .text2XL {
    font-size: 16px;
  }
}

.textLarge {
  font-size: 1vw;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .textLarge {
    font-size: 14px;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 376px) and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .textLarge {
    font-size: 15px;
  }
}

.textSmall {
  font-size: 0.8vw;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: var(--white);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .textSmall {
    font-size: 16px;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1001px) and (max-width: 1100px) {
  .textSmall {
    font-size: calc(0.75vw + 0.2vw);
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1101px) and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .textSmall {
    font-size: calc(0.75vw + 0.125vw);
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1201px) and (max-width: 1300px) {
  .textSmall {
    font-size: calc(0.75vw + 0.1vw);
  }
}

.textExtraSmall {
  font-size: small;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: var(--white);
}

.textNormal {
  font-size: 1vw;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: var(--white);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .textNormal {
    font-size: 14px;
  }
}

.textPrimary {
  color: var(--primary);
}

.textWhite {
  color: var(--white);
}

.textCenter {
  text-align: center;
}

.fstItalic {
  font-style: italic;
}

.textGlow {
  text-shadow: 0 0 2px var(--white);
}

.textGlowPrimary {
  text-shadow: 0 0 1.5px var(--primary);
}

.letterSpacingDefault {
  letter-spacing: 0.1vw;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .letterSpacingDefault {
    letter-spacing: 1px;
  }
}

.relative {
  position: relative;
}

.textRevealInitial {
  opacity: 0;
  filter: blur(6px);
  transition: opacity 650ms linear, filter 650ms linear;
}

.textRevealAnimation {
  opacity: 1;
  filter: blur(0px);
}

.defaultButtonHover {
  transition: 0.1s linear;
}

.defaultButtonHover:hover {
  background-color: var(--button-bg-white-hover);
}

I checked with the desktop chrome dev tools, it works fine there. But it just breaks when I switch to android browser desktop site mode. Is this a css issue or nextjs issue?
Edit 1:
Added screenshot:
This is how it looks in desktop mode

How is the css module being imported and used?

Could you describe further what 'breaks' means? A picture of the resulting problem might be helpful.

your css is a little messy. mixing of px and calc(vm * vm) lots of media querys. try to organise the css better it should be easy. Maybe make a JSFIddle for demo..

@Asplund I import them into individual component if needed like. Eg:
import defaultStyles from "@/styles/default.module.css";
Text
@AHaworth I have now added the screenshot. Please check them.

@JJaun I agree. But the code is not ready yet. Will update it soon.

@everyone Thing is this issue only occurs in chrome, samsung internet and some other browsers not in Kiwi browser. And everything works perfectly fine in desktop (pc) chrome dev tools.

@DBS Thanks! I was copy pasting the code somewhere the "@" char was replaced automatically. My fault.

@rkrish I better formatted your css because it was terribly hard to read .. especially because you mixed media queries with regular selectors and it was hard to understand the scope of each rule. By the way given the problem as you describe it occurring in some specific scenarios, maybe it's related to the fact that you may have media queries converging on the same scenario but setting font-size differently.

Just now checked the website on firefox android and brave browser by switching to desktop site. It works fine on firefox but not on Brave browser. To summarize the font size works fine in desktop site mode only in firefox and kiwi so far.

@RKrish it's hard to deal with reactive code that needs to be tested as a whole instead of focusing on a single vanilla page. So all I can suggest is: track down the elements having the uneven font size at runtime; understand which css rules they are engaging for having such style; narrow down which exact selectors are having the issues so you can understand which are the media queries engaging at those conditions that are setting those weird font size.

Otherwise the real solution would be to just throw anything and start again making things consistent from the ground up. Your media queries have different breakpoints that may overlap in some conditions while acting on different selectors with different font size. You should have a set of non overlapping breakpoints and put the rules in blocks so they are consistent. Plus you should take a more solid choice on how you compute font size instead of each one having a different strategy

Or as a last resort just slim down the problem by crafting a vanilla html that will reproduce the problem so that asking here will be easier for anyone to give a solid answer

@DiegoD Okay I guess I should use chrome remote debug tool as the browsers which the font size is weird do not have Dev tools at all.

ok but you know in advance which elements are the culprit... because even when it's working on regular chrome, you can see which are the "sections" that on other conditions don't behave correctly. So how would you know which rules where engaged in the browser/device/screen where things don't work properly without using the inspector? you may add css rules using pseudoselectors adding content for diagnosing.. something like .class::before{ content: 'this is the breakpoint x'; border: solid 1px red; } ... inside each category you want to investigate inside each media query

but I insist that it would be so easy to just "dump" the html document once it's rendered in a working environment with chrome for example, save it to a simple html file and then test it where it's not supposed to work. If the conditions match what you experience in the full reactive application, you have your snippet to ask for help. If you just point people to a whole application they cannot browse it entirely until they found what you showed in the picture. People needs to see the dom ready to easily pinpoint the problem.

@DiegoD Okay thanks for the help.
